# Filter the data for particular 15 days of all years in django

Tags: django

I am trying to print the data for particular 15 days of every year.

For example to get the Employee's details who has birthdays with in 15 days.

```
today = datetime.now()
start_day = today.day
start_month = today.month
end_day = today + timedelta(days=15)
end_date = end_day.day
end_month = end_day.month
user_dob_obj = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(date_of_birth__month__gte=start_month, date_of_birth__day__gte=start_day) &
         Q(date_of_birth__month__lte=end_month, date_of_birth__day__lte=end_date))
```

Comment: Does what you have not work? Looks like it should work just fine, just the `Q` objects are unnecessary: `.filter(date_of_birth__month__gte=start_month, date_of_birth__day__gte=start_day, date_of_birth__month__lte=end_month, date_of_birth__day__lte=end_date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Sorry I misunderstood your question. You can use if statement to check if the month is the same 15 days later. Then use the `or` logical operation to make sure birthdays in current and next month are filtered.

```
today = datetime.now()
end_date = today + timedelta(days=15)
if today.month == end_date.month:
    user_dob_obj = user_dob_obj.filter(date_of_birth__month=today.month, date_of_birth__day__gte=today.day, date_of_birth__day__lte=end_date.day)
else:
    user_dob_obj = queryset.filter(Q(date_of_birth__month=today.month, date_of_birth__day__gte=today.day) | Q(date_of_birth__month=end_date.month, date_of_birth__day__lte=end_date.day))
```

Comment: range(today, end_day) contains this current year but the employee birth day

Comment: should not not be the current year

Comment: @savithri from my understanding, you're trying to get all birthdays that are within 15 days. If that's the case, then the above should work fine. I don't know what else you could mean.

Comment: In my db the dob is like 1994-04-25 but is will fail in this case.

Comment: @almostabeginner OP is trying to get objects in a 15 day window of **every year**.

Comment: @savithri Sorry, I understand now. I updated my answer.

Comment: @anonymous your answer in the comment section should do the trick. I learned something from it, thanks.